# VSCode, User Snippets doesn't show $ when used

Tags: javascript, php, visual-studio-code

I have this user sniped to quickly inserts a debug command but when done, it doesn't show the "$" sign.

```
"Debug MySQL": {
   "prefix": "debug",
      "body": [
          "lib::$db->debug = true;"
        ],
    "description": "debug MySQL"
},
```

When `debug` used I get this:

```
lib::db->debug = true;
```

Any ideas what might be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put other dollar to escape the first one: `lib::$$db->debug = true;`